# get the value in a javascript callback function into an input field

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript callback function that returns a response with a value a value upon a success call. Here is a sample of the function

```
callback: function(response) {            
    var response : response.reference;    
    alert('success. transaction ref is ' + response.reference);
}
```

now I want to pass the response into a form input text below immediately the callback function is called after checking if the response variable is not null

```
<form action="" method="post">                  
    <input id="response" type="hidden" value="javascript value"/>
    <button id="submit" type="button"> Submit </button>                                           
</form>
```

Comment: should `var response : response.reference` be `var response = response.reference` and `alert('success. transaction ref is ' + response);` be `

Comment: document.getElementById("response").value = response;

Comment: In the alert function, `response.reference` equals to `response.reference.reference`

Comment: passing it to the form is the major challenge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweak it to suit your need; but the core idea is same;

change type attribute from 'hidden' to 'text' and set value from response;

```js
let response = "someResponse";

if(response != null) {
document.getElementById('response').setAttribute('type','text');
document.getElementById('response').value = response;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">                 
  <input id="response" type="hidden" value="javascript value"/>
  <button id="submit" type="button"> Submit </button>
</form>
```